# Add repeated content in middle of tab delimited file using awk/sed

Tags: linux, text, sed, awk

I have a text file (tab delimited) and I need to add a new header row in line 3

```
[Tab] ABC123   ABC124
[Tab] High     High
ENSG  8.9      7.2
```

The new line I want to be will be line 3, and then I'll want to print European 5 times, tab between each of them, then Asian 6 times, tab between each of them...

```
[Tab] ABC123   ABC124
[Tab] High     High    
[Tab] European European [this will be the new line]
ENSG  8.9      7.2
```

I'm think of using sed so that I can use

sed '4 i'

But I don't really know how to do the actually printing/appending of new content into that new line I'm guessing I'd need to start /European/\t/a or similar.

Basically struggling, probably because I'm not googling intelligently!

Comment: You want to *insert* a new line, or *replace* an existing line?

Comment: consider editing your question to show the exact inputs, and output you require, rather than a verbal description. Verbal descriptions create ambiguity ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed '3i\ \tEuropean\tEuropean' file`:

```
$ cat file
        ABC123          ABC124
        High            High
ENSG    8.9             7.2

$ sed '3i\ \tEuropean\tEuropean' file
        ABC123          ABC124
        High            High
        European        European
ENSG    8.9             7.2
```

**Edit:**

I probably do something like this  `awk 'NR==3{for(i=0;i<10;i++)s=s"\tEuropean";print s}1'`:

```
$ awk 'NR==3{for(i=0;i<10;i++)s=s"\tEuropean";print s}1' file
        ABC123          ABC124
        High            High
        European        European        European    European    European    European    European    European    European    European
ENSG    8.9             7.2
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I make that more flexible, eg can I get it to print European 10 times without have to type it out each time?

Comment: If I wantd to type European 10 times and then Asian 5 times -

    awk 'NR==3{for(i=0;i<10;i++)s=s"\tEuropean";print s; for(i=0;i<5;i++)s=s"\tAsian";print s}1' file ?

Comment: Almost you only want to print once though `awk 'NR==3{for(i=0;i<10;i++)s=s"\tEuropean";for(i=0;i<5;i++)s=s"\tAsian";print s}1'`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.   One technique is:

```
t="$(printf \\t)"  # Assign t to be a string with one tab
sed -e '4i\
European${t}European...
' input-file > output-file
```

With some shells, you can do things like `t=$"\t"`, and with some `sed` you do not need a literal newline after the `i`, but the above is pretty portable.  An you can always use a literal `tab` (you might need to type `ctrl-v tab` at an interactive prompt).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU):

```
sed -r '2!b;G;:a;/(\tEuropean){10}/!s/$/\tEuropean/;ta' file
```

Where `10` can be any number of the repeated field `\tEuropean`

Comment: Hmm, looks like I don't have GNU sed: s/: Event not found